# Designer.cs file not created on creating new LINQ to SQL class

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-sql

New to ASP and LINQ. 
I'm developing a website using ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2010. I'm trying to create a linq to SQL class (dbml file) by right clicking on app_code->Add New Item. I specify the name of the dbml file and click on 'Add'. The OR designer opens up and get an error list that says 'The custom tool 'MSLinqToSQLGenerator' failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object'. I see that only the layout file is created, and designer.cs file is not created.

I currently have a connection string setup to access the database server from my laptop.  I'm able to add GridViews to my aspx pages and retrieve data using a SqlDataSource.

I've tried searching for help on this issue; a possible solution was to reset the packages by running "devenv/resetskippkgs" from the VS command prompt. But that didn't work as well.

Any help?

Comment: You get an error with a fresh, empty dbml?

Comment: @usr: Yes I get an error as soon as I create a fresh, empty dbml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, it would be better if you reinstall your visual studio

Comment: Yes I did reinstall it, and got several errors while reinstalling it. I gave it up as I'm hard pressed for time, and now am using my friend's laptop on which it is working fine.